# How to run a springmvc+gradle project from command line?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, gradle

In my springmvc project, I use gradle as a build tool.

But our FE developers always complain about that why they have to start the project in IntelliJ IDEA, but they don't use the IDE as their editor at all.

so, recently I made a lot of research on running my project from command line.

Please help.

Comment: Have you read about docker image?

Comment: @Lemmy  Yes , I considered using docker, But I'm not sure will the project's freemarker and frontend resources be updated while changed from editor. do you have any ideas or experience?

Answer (score 0):

If gradle is used and all is configured well, try gradle run while using the application plugin.

You do need to load the plugin

```
apply plugin: 'application'
```

and define the main class of your application

```
mainClassName = "org.gradle.sample.Main"
```

Further parameters can be defined as well.